# Using a Haml helper method with haml_tag to make a rails view DRY-er

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a view that displays a list of items. Each item has several places where you can click to  launch the same Bootstrap modal. I want to write a helper method to replace the redundant code, but I'm new to haml and can't get the helper method to work. I've tried to read the documentation on Haml::Helpers but am not clear about how everything fits together.

**Redundant Code**

```
{"data-target" => "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}", 
 "data-toggle" => "modal",       
  href: "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}"}
```

**Redundant code wrapped in helper method**

```
module OpportunitiesHelper
    def modal_tag (type)
        haml_tag type, {"data-target" => "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}", "data-toggle" => "modal", href: "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}"}
    end
end
```

**Snippet from current view**

```
%li
.item.col-sm-4
  %button{"data-target" => "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}", 
         "data-toggle" => "modal", 
          href: "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}"} 
      Quick View

.col-sm-8
  %a{"data-target" => "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}", 
           "data-toggle" => "modal", 
            href: "#opportunityModal#{opportunity.id}"}
    = opportunity.title

= render :partial => "opportunities/modal", :locals => { :opportunity => opportunity}
```

**Same view using helper method**

```
%li
.item.col-sm-4
  -modal_tag(:button)
      Quick View

.col-sm-8
  -modal_tag(:a)
    = opportunity.title

= render :partial => "opportunities/modal", :locals => { :opportunity => opportunity}
```

**Resulting error when I try to use the helper method**

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely going to need a block.

```
- modal_helper(:a, opportunity.id) do
  Quick View
```

I would do something like this:

```
def modal_helper(type, id, &block)
  content_tag(type, href: "#opportunityModal#{id}", data: { target: "#opportunityModal#{id}", toggle: "modal" }) &block
end
```

That should get you pretty close. There might be some weirdness around blocks and outputting html. You might need html_safe, for instance.